# How to obtain the href element using RSelenium from this code?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am using Rselenium to obtain an URL, and I don't understand why is not working.

My code:

```
    links <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", value = "//*[@class 
    = 
    'item-info']")
     final_link <- data.frame(link = unlist(sapply(links, function(x) 
     {x$getElementAttribute('href')})))
```

The code of the page:

```
<div class="item-info">
<p class="title product-field" translate="no" data-track-info=" 
{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;title&quot;}" data-force-track="">
       <a href="https://www.kobo.com/us/en/ebook/added-youth" 
 class="">Added Youth</a>
 </p>
 <p class="subtitle product-field" translate="no" data-track-info=" 
     {&quot;description&quot;:&quot;subtitle&quot;}" data-force-track="">
       <a href="https://www.kobo.com/us/en/ebook/added-youth" class="">All Natural Anti-Aging Program</a>
  </p>
```

The expected result is the link, in this case: 
     https://www.kobo.com/us/en/ebook/added-youth

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
page <- read_html(paste0(urls1[[i]]))

links <- page %>% 
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      html_attr("href")
```