# RSelenium Disappearing Link / Overlay Pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

Hopefully I've got an interesting problem for you all. I'm trying to get information on German *Abgeordnete* (basically representatives/delegates) and they have a really nice webpage that is unfortunately a bit too interactive to get at with `rvest`. So I thought it was time to dip my toes in `RSelenium`.

The following code gets the home page up in the remote browser:

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate('https://www.bundestag.de/abgeordnete')
```

Here's what that looks like:
[image: This is what the page looks like.]

I was able to get the both the next page arrow and select the 12 people with the following code:=

```
next_el <- remDr$findElement('xpath', 
'//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "slick-next", " " ))]')

people_el <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath',
                                      '//*[(@id = "modul-biografien")]//h3')
```

But then everything sort of falls apart. Clicking on any given person opens this overlay page that my selector really hates.

Looking for a workaround, I noticed that if I drag my mouse over the *Abgeordnete*'s name (on that page pictured above) I get a nice clean link to a standalone page for that delegate. But that information seems nowhere present in anything RSelenium has access to.

Any tips? Feel free to suggest anything way out of left field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to match, those links you see on mouseover, by combination of [css class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) with descendant combinator

```
.bt-slide-content .bt-open-in-overlay
```

Then from that returned nodeList extract the href attributes.

Syntax, from looking at [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670026/how-to-obtain-the-href-element-using-rselenium-from-this-code) should be something like

```
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".bt-slide-content .bt-open-in-overlay")
links <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x) {x$getElementAttribute('href')}))
```